# Authentication with SUAP API Keys and return the formatted student report card to the terminal

Tags: python, terminal

My problem itself is to create a client that authenticates with the SUAP API Keys (https://suap.ifrn.edu.br/api/) and returns the student's report card formatted in the terminal. But outside of this global context, and going to the specific point of my problem: in the vs code terminal, my program asks for the SUAP username and password (suap.ifrn.edu.br), but when I type both, it gives this error:

> PS C:\Users\20201181110024> & "C:/Program Files/Python311/python.exe" c:/Users/20201181110024/Downloads/suap.py
> user: 20201181110024
> Password:
> "{'refresh': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTcwMDIzMTkwOSwiaWF0IjoxNzAwMTQ1NTA5LCJqdGkiOiJmOTU5ZWE4YzJjMmI 0MDk1OWFjYTQ4Njg1MGFmOWZhMiIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjI5MTEwNX0.3oPrSwQSF80fYh7jBjMYWdxVov9GSVi-mzazSKZZAW4', 'access': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.ey J0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNzAwMTQ1ODA5LCJpYXQiOjE3MDAxNDU1MDksImp0aSI6Ijk3MWY2ZTA5NDczODRjNGNhNTQ3MDI3ODAzMGI5MGU4IiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MjkxMTA1 fQ.nvVZzhpWka3vgqllwi22lZ0PSxujt0hwKikJ5jzct-A'}
> Student Information:
> {'id': 337471, 'matricula': '20201181110024', 'usual_name': 'JOAO AUGUSTO', 'cpf': '707.428.894-24', 'rg': 'None - / - ', 'filiacao' : [None, None], 'date_birth': '2005-07-14', 'naturality': '-', 'tipo_sanguineo': 'NoneNone', 'email': 'joao.venancio@academico.ifrn.edu. br', 'url_foto_75x100': '/media/pessoas/75x100/267886.dFIkCrdRBdyb.jpg', 'url_foto_150x200': '/media/pessoas/150x200/267886.dFIkCrdRBdyb.jpg', 'tipo_vinculo': 'Aluno', ' link': {'matricula': '20201181110024', 'name': 'JOÃO AUGUSTO VENANCIO DA SILVA', 'course': 'Middle Level Technician in Internet Computing', 'campus': 'SPP', 'situacao' : 'Enrolled', 'cota_sistec': '', 'cota_mec': '', 'situacao_sistemica': 'Enrolled in SUAP', 'matricula_regular': False, 'linha_pesquisa': None, 'curriculo_lattes': 'https:// wwws.cnpq.br/cvlattesweb/PKG_MENU.menu?f_cod=3FE036E2BA9D1577D4A555FAFEC594AF'}}
> PS C:\Users\20201181110024>"

Meu código é este:

```py
import requests
from getpass import getpass

api_url = "https://suap.ifrn.edu.br/api/"

user = input("user: ")
password = getpass()

data = {"username": user, "password": password}

response = requests.post(api_url + "v2/autenticacao/token/", json=data)

if response.status_code == 200:
    token = response.json().get("access")
    print(response.json())

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f'Bearer {token}'
    }

    response_meus_dados = requests.get(api_url + "v2/minhas-informacoes/meus-dados/", headers=headers)

    if response_meus_dados.status_code == 200:
        print("Informações do Aluno:")
        print(response_meus_dados.json())
    else:
        print(f"Erro ao obter informações. Código de status: {response_meus_dados.status_code}")
else:
    print("Erro na autenticação. Verifique seu usuário e senha.")
```